# Implicitly launch detached program (&) from terminal

Tags: bash, emacs, terminal

I feel sure this will end up as a duplicate, but I don't know how to word it so that I can search for it...

I like to do my programming in emacs, which I launch from the terminal. When I use my mac I use aquamacs and the command

```
aquamacs Program.py
```

will launch aquamacs in a separate window ready to edit Program.py. When I work on my linux machine however to get the same result I must type

```
emacs Program.py &
```

And I'm always forgetting the "&". So 70% of the time I end up closing the emacs window, and relaunching again with the "&". Now I understand why that "&" is there, but is there a way to set up my system so that the command

```
emacs Program.py
```

always launches as a detached process? The only time I might not want that behavior is if I was SSHing in over a slow connection, in which case I usually use "-nw" anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can click on the terminal and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Z</kbd> to move an already running foreground process to the background.

Alternatively you could add this function to your `~/.bashrc`:

```
emacs() {
    command emacs "$@" &
}
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks, but now if I do "emacs Program.py -nw" it no longer works. Not critical, but any thoughts?

Comment: @EddyTheB I'd say just do Ctrl-Z if you forget to put the ampersand.

Answer (score 0):

For the specific case of emacs, I use a shell script, which is more complicated than this but for your purposes boils down to

```
#!/bin/csh -f
/bin/emacs $*:q &
```

Put it in a directory which is earlier in your $path than where the "real" emacs is, and replace /bin/emacs with the real path to emacs on your system.